# I have a small registration Form with 4 fields

Tags: c#, sql

The fields are

```
employeeID  int 
name  varchar
Gender int  (0 = male, 1 = female)
Date datetime
```

Now if i am writing select query like this

```
select employeeID,name,Gender,Date 
from empTable 
where employeeID=@id
```

I get result

```
'101','cccc','1','11/1/2014'
```

But i need a query its give me

```
'101','cccc','Female','11/1/2014'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** this is Sql Server you can use a CASE statement.

```
select employeeID
  ,name
  ,case when Gender = 1 then 'Female' else 'Male' end AS Gender
  ,Date 
from empTable 
where employeeID=@id
```

---

[IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) statement

```
select employeeID
  ,name
  , IIF(Gender = 1, 'Female', 'Male') AS Gender
  ,Date 
from empTable 
where employeeID=@id
```

Comment: Or a simple `IIF`

Comment: can you please give an example with IIF

Comment: @nik - any reason you removed the answer check/mark?